# Material UI Grid width shrinks on every re-render

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to render a list of 25 words on a 5x5 grid using the MUI `Grid` component. The 5x5 grid itself is a `<Grid container direction="column">` containing five `<Grid item>`. Within each of those five `<Grid item>` is the following structure:

```js
<Grid container direction = "row">
  <Grid item xs={2} key={1}>
    <Paper>
      <Typography> word </Typography>
    </Paper>
  <Grid>
  <Grid item xs={2} key={2}>
    ...
  </Grid>
  ...
  <Grid item xs={2} key={5}>
    ...
  </Grid>
</Grid>
```

It renders as expected initially. However, whenever the component re-renders, the width of the grid decreases bit-by-bit on each re-render.

I've recreated the issue here:

[image: Edit MUI Grid Shrink Bug]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You `<Grid item>` has no size defined. Set size accordingly :

**Example**

```
<Grid container direction = "row">
  <Grid item  xs={12} sm={6} md={3} lg={3} xl={2}>
    <Paper>
      <Typography> word </Typography>
    </Paper>
  <Grid>
</Grid>
```

Also there is no prop for Grid like `key`. Its a attribute for React to identify component in a map function. It has nothing to do with material UI

**Updated**

From

```
<Grid item md={12}>
 <Grid container alignItems="center" justify="center">
   {wordRows}
 </Grid>
</Grid>
```

To

```
<Grid item container alignItems="center" justify="center">
   {wordRows}
</Grid>
```

Comment: I've used `xs={2}` in the grid items (I had added them in the codesandbox example but forgot to include them in the snippet here. I've edited the post to add that now). I need `xs={2}` as I need this to be a 5x5 grid on all screens. This does not fix the issue though. The key prop was added to the code as the grid items are generated in a for-loop. I added it here so that it was clear that there are 5 items within the container.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Do you know why exactly this is happening?

Comment: Though I am not a master of this but in my understanding,Item is a block element . Container is a Flex item which have a property name `flex-shrink: 4;` so it was flexibly shrinking, relative to its parent, Item was not preventing it as it has no width define. SO when container was shrinking, item was also sjrinking.